Weird results with int() function in tikz-pgfplot
Maybe I found a new bug in tikz-pgfplot. Can you confirm this weird result:
\pgfmathparse{int(11/2)}
return 0
@JeT
This is my piece of code that generates that issue with int():
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{int(11/2)}
    \pgfmathresult %correctly returns 5 as JeT said, but
    
\begin{figure} % this plot is wrong as int(11/2) returns 0 for instance
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=1.0,
        declare function={
            bit(\c,\i)=int(\c/2^\i)-2*int(\c/2^(\i+1)); %Compute the n-th binary digit of c. Both n and c must be integers
        }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10 cm,
            height=6 cm,
            xlabel = {\large $C$},
            ylabel = {\large digit 0 of $C$},
            minor tick num=5,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 20,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 1,
            ]
            \addplot [samples at={0,...,20}, ycomb, mark=*] {bit(x,0)}; % check for debugging purpose
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test int()}
    \label{fig:Test int()}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}

I can figure out what is going wrong.

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{int(11/2)}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}``` gives 5 and not 0.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a complete example. Also, when suggesting that there is a problem, it is also good to mention what TeX system you are using.

@Praecipua This could be related to how your bit is evaluated.

@ JeT I just discovered that my function 'bit' works fine calling it outside the 'figure' environment  but it doesn't inside. Apparently inside the figure environment, int(11/1) returns 10.

The same problem happens with 13, 16 and 18. The PGFPlots package activates the fpu library which implements almost all PGFMath functions. It seems to have trouble with some cases in the int function. Ah, it evaluates 11.0/1.0 to 10.9999 and similar for the others.

Different approach with a loop in the axis environment.

\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% \begin{figure}
%     \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=1.0,
        declare function={
            bit(\c,\i)=int(\c/2^\i)-2*int(\c/2^(\i+1)); %Compute the n-th binary digit of c. Both n and c must be integers
        }
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10 cm,
            height=6 cm,
            xlabel = {\large $C$},
            ylabel = {\large digit 0 of $C$},
            minor tick num=5,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            xtick={0,...,20},
            ytick={0,1},
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 20,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 1,
            ]
            \foreach \x in {0,...,20}{% here you'll use a loop in the axis
                \pgfmathparse{bit(\x,0)}
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(\x, \pgfmathresult)};}
                \temp
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%     \caption{Test int()}
%     \label{fig:Test int()}
% \end{figure}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot. This solution, at the moment, help me going on with my document. Regards.

@Praecipua Great. Someone will probably come up with a better solution....
